# How to share and update resources (KO observables) across different AMD modules without introducing tight coupling?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm a JavaScript newbie and I'm trying to create a web application with three AMD modules - Parent, ChildA & ChildB. The Parent module has a KO observable which stores the parent's name. Both the child pages should be able to read the Parent's name. But I don't want to add a dependency between the Parent and the Child modules. Instead, I want to store the Parent's name in a globally shared object which can be accessed by all three modules.

Currently, this object stores the value of Parent's name and all the modules are able to access it. But whenever I make any changes to the Parent's name, the change is not getting reflected in the Child modules. Only the Parent module can change the Parent's name and I want the child modules to be synchronized with the changed Parent name.

Since the Parent's name is a KO observable, I can add the Parent dependency to the child modules and subscribe to the changes. But I'm trying to avoid tight coupling between these modules.

Code with tight coupling between modules (which i want to eliminate):

Parent.js:

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
    this.ParentName = ko.observable("Ross");
});
```

ChildA.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'Parent'], function (ko, parent) {
    this.AParent = ko.observable();

    parent.ParentName.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        this.AParent(newValue);
    });
});
```

ChildB.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'Parent'], function (ko, parent) {
    this.BParent = ko.observable();

    parent.ParentName.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        this.BParent(newValue);
    });
});
```

Code with the shared object - unable to update the object's value in child modules:

SharedObject.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'jquery', 'lodash'], function (ko, $, _) {
    var sharedObj = {};
    //create a map
    return sharedObj;
});
```

Parent.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'SharedObject'], function (ko, so) {
    this.ParentName = ko.observable("Ross");
    so.put('ParentName', this.ParentName);
});
```

ChildA.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'SharedObject'], function (ko, so) {
    this.AParent = ko.observable(so.get('ParentName'));
});
```

ChildB.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'SharedObject'], function (ko, so) {
    this.BParent = ko.observable(so.get('ParentName'));
});
```

Please suggest a way to notify the child modules about the change happening in the sharedObject. Or is there any other way to remove tight coupling between these modules?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which js framework are you using? I would suggest to define each child as a dependency on parent and on any updates to the object, you can let the children know about it by updating variables in each child...for the reverse case, you could use a `pub-sub` sort of mechanism to let the parent know that the object has been updated in a child...

Comment: I'm using Oracle JET. Could you please explain how to add a child as a dependency on the parent?

Comment: The syntax should be the same as what you have for adding the child as a dependency on parent. 
`define(['knockout', 'childA', 'childB'], function (ko, childA, childB) {
    this.parentName = "Ross";
    childA.parentName = ko.observable(this.name);
    childB.parentName = ko.observable(this.name);
});`

Comment: @gkb I want to eliminate tight coupling between modules. I want to notify the child modules using the shared object (second approach).

Comment: Check out this https://technology.amis.nl/2016/02/13/introducing-the-client-side-event-bus-in-oracle-jet-for-decoupled-interactions-across-templates-view-models-and-modules-with-knockout-postbox/

Comment: @gkb I used knockout-postbox and it solved my problem. Please post this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you post it with all the relevant details..don't forget to accept that as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem can be found in this link:

https://technology.amis.nl/2016/02/13/introducing-the-client-side-event-bus-in-oracle-jet-for-decoupled-interactions-across-templates-view-models-and-modules-with-knockout-postbox/

E.g.

Parent.js

```
define (['knockout', ‘knockout-postbox’], function (ko) {
    this.name = ko.observable("Ross");
    ko.postbox.publish("parentName", {‘name': this.name()});
});
```

ChildA.js

```
define (['knockout', ‘knockout-postbox’], function (ko) {
    this.Aname = ko.observable();
    ko.postbox.subscribe("parentName", function (newValue) {
        this.Aname(newValue.name); //Ross
    });
});
```

ChildB.js

```
define (['knockout', ‘knockout-postbox’], function (ko) {
    this.Bname = ko.observable();
    ko.postbox.subscribe("parentName", function (newValue) {
        this.Bname(newValue.name); //Ross
    });
});
```